# Discrete-time model for spread of information when the probability of information transfer between each pair is known

Tags: pr.probability, mathematical-modeling

[This question is cross-posted from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4231725/modelling-spread-of-information).]

I'm interested in the behaviour of the following sort of system.

We are given:
a finite set $X$,
a subset $A_0 \subset X$, and
a function $f : X \times X \to [0,1]$ such that $f(x,x) = 1$ for all $x \in X$.

(It's supposed to model how a particular piece of information spreads, where:
$X$ is some community,
$A_0$ is the members who already know that information, and
$f(x,y)$ is the probability that $x$ tells that information to $y$ in a unit of time.)

Then we successively generate $A_{n+1}$ according to:
the probability of $x$ being in $A_{n+1}$ is given by
$$P(x \in A_{n+1}) = 1-\prod_{a \in A_n}(1-f(a,x)).$$
In particular, $x \in A_n$ implies $x \in A_{n+1}$.

Has this sort of thing been studied before?
In particular, I would be interested to know:

- Given $x \in X$ and $n \ge 0$, is there an efficient way to compute $P(x \in A_n)$?
- What if $f$ varies with time?

(The emphasis is on "efficient" here; one can turn this into a Markov process with state space $2^X$, but I'd prefer dealing with something smaller.)

---

I believe the hardest part is dealing with dependency.
For a fixed path $\pi = (x_0 \to x_1 \to \dots \to x_n)$, of course the probability $P(\pi)$ of the corresponding event happening (i.e. the information reaching from $x_0$ to $x_n$ via this particular route) can be calculated as $\prod_{1 \le i \le n}f(x_{i-1},x_i)$.
But there can be many such paths, and what's unclear is how to combine them.

Just summing the probabilities for all possible paths would overestimate the total probability since you are essentially assuming those events to be mutually exclusive.
Something a little more sophisticated like $1-\prod_\pi(1-P(\pi))$ still doesn't work since, in this case, you are assuming the events to be totally independent from each other when different paths can still have common edges.
For example, consider: $X = \{a,b,x,y\}$, $A_0 = \{a,b\}$, $f(a,x)=f(b,x)=f(x,y) = 1/2$ and $f$ takes the value $0$ elsewhere.
Then we should get $P(y \in A_2) = 3/8$, but this formula yields $7/16$.

The best I could come up with was a step-by-step version of the above formula.
That is, enumerate $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_r\}$ and consider the $r$-by-$r$ matrix $M$ defined by $M_{ij} = f(x_i,x_j)$.
Compute the $n$-th "power" $M^n$ but with the modified addition $$a \oplus b = 1-(1-a)(1-b) = a+b-ab$$ in place of the usual addition of real numbers.
(This definition of $M^n$ is actually ambiguous since the modified matrix multiplication is not associative; let's say we choose the left bracketing.)
Then the $(i,j)$-component of $M^n$ approximates the probability that the information reaches from $x_i$ to $x_j$ by time $n$.
This gives us the right probability for the specific example described in the previous paragraph, but in general it still suffers from the same sort of (wrong) independence assumption.

---

Even just pointing to the right term to search would be very appreciated.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: As written, the problem looks exactly like a Markov chain, but with state space of size $|X|$, not $2^{|X|}$, so should be able to operate efficiently; moreover, time-varying behavior in $f$ would correspond to a non-homogeneous Markov chain (which can still be updated efficiently).  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the nature of the dependency you outline? Given your defining equation for $A_{n+1}$, though, I think that's already the kind of dependency that a MC handles.

Comment: You are describing the "rumour spreading" model. This is a very well known stuff, and it has been studied in graphs where you pick a random vertex of it, and such vertex sends its information to a random neighbour. Have a look at https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~maajg/teaching/complexnets/rumours.pdf

Comment: @NicolasRivera Thank you, that is indeed exactly the sort of thing I was thinking about! Do you happen to know any book/journal article on this topic too (so that I can find out what else is known about such systems by following references)? When I searched "rumour spreading model" online, all I could find was variants of SIR models trying to capture how *fake* news spreads...

Comment: @BillBradley If one formulates this as a Markov process, the states need to encode "which members of $X$ currently have the information". So I believe the state space is going to be essentially the power set of $X$ (or more precisely, the set of subsets of $X$ containing $A_0$).

Comment: @TheMoreTheMerrier A lot of the models can look very similar, for example, the SI model is a sort of rumour spreading model. The problem is that people use different metaphors and sometimes they refer to the same object. I guess infections, rumours and voting are the most common ones. 

Books: - Probability on Graphs by Geoffrey Grimmett
            - Epidemics and Rumours in Complex Networks by Draief and Massoulie 
            - you can also have a look at some interacting particles systems books, however they tend to focus on infinite lattices and stuff like that